# SQL INSERT INTO does not work my Access database

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, syntax-error, insert-into

I work with a somewhat old software (2000's) that interfaces with MS Access. I am using Python to write the MDB files that I need to insert into the software. I need to update the values of 7 different tables in order to get the expected value. For all the 7 tables I am using the following code:

```
def sql_cols(df):
    cols_aux = tuple(df.columns)
    cols_aux = str(cols_aux).replace("'","")
    cols_aux = cols_aux.replace(', DESC', ', [DESC]')
    return cols_aux


for k in range(len(df)):
    vals = tuple(list(df.iloc[k]))
    cols = sql_cols(df)
    action = 'INSERT INTO Strategy {columns} VALUES {values}'.format(columns = cols, values = str(vals).replace("'",''))
    cursor.execute(action)
    conn.commit()
```

In 6 tables this procedure works, however i keep getting ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. (-3502) (SQLExecDirectW)') in the last table. the action statement for that table is something like:

```
'INSERT INTO Strategy (STRATGY_ID, NUMBUDGETS, PDISC_RATE, INC_IMPS, OPT_METHOD, OBJ_FUNC, MININCVAL, EFFFZONE, BUDGETPD, REPORTING, NUM_GROUPS, MATRIX_DEF, NAME, [DESC], FLT_CONRTE, WRK_CONRTE, NET_CONRTE, START_YEAR, END_YEAR, CURRENCY, FLEET, NETWORK, NUM_SECSEL, NUM_VEHSEL, ANAL_MODE, NUMPRJOPTS, NUMSECOPTS, INC_NMT, DOECONANAL, DISC_RATE, BASE_OPTN, ACCCOSTS, FATALCOST, INJURYCOST, DAMAGECOST, ALLACCCOST, ENERGY, EMISSIONS, ACCLEFFECT, LOGFILE, INCSENSTVY, NUMSENSCEN, DOASSETVAL, EXCVEHDATA, EXCPERDATA) 
VALUES (0, 0,  , 0, 1, 0, 0, 95, 0, -1, 0, 0, Road_Networks_PA,  , 1, 1, 1, 2019, 2038, Reais, Vehicles 2017, Road_Networks_PA, 157, 12, 0,  , 157, -1, -1, 6.49,  , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  , 0, -1, -1)'
```

I've already tried to ut all columns in square brackets, [], but it didn't work also. Can anyone help-me with this problem?

**Edit:** Following Gordon's advice, I altered the code, but the same error appears:

```
for k in range(len(df)):
    vals = tuple(list(df.iloc[k]))
    cols = sql_cols(df)
    action = 'INSERT INTO Strategy {columns} VALUES {values}'.format(columns = cols, values = str(vals))
    cursor.execute(action)
    conn.commit()
```

and the action statement is:

```
"INSERT INTO Strategy (STRATGY_ID, NUMBUDGETS, PDISC_RATE, INC_IMPS, OPT_METHOD, OBJ_FUNC, MININCVAL, EFFFZONE, BUDGETPD, REPORTING, NUM_GROUPS, MATRIX_DEF, NAME, [DESC], FLT_CONRTE, WRK_CONRTE, NET_CONRTE, START_YEAR, END_YEAR, CURRENCY, FLEET, NETWORK, NUM_SECSEL, NUM_VEHSEL, ANAL_MODE, NUMPRJOPTS, NUMSECOPTS, INC_NMT, DOECONANAL, DISC_RATE, BASE_OPTN, ACCCOSTS, FATALCOST, INJURYCOST, DAMAGECOST, ALLACCCOST, ENERGY, EMISSIONS, ACCLEFFECT, LOGFILE, INCSENSTVY, NUMSENSCEN, DOASSETVAL, EXCVEHDATA, EXCPERDATA) 
VALUES (0, 0, ' ', 0, 1, 0, 0, 95, 0, -1, 0, 0, 'Road_Networks_PA', ' ', 1, 1, 1, 2019, 2038, 'Reais', 'Vehicles 2017', 'Road_Networks_PA', 157, 12, 0, ' ', 157, -1, -1, 6.49, ' ', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ' ', 0, -1, -1)"
```

**Edit 2:** As asked by Kshitij Saxena, here are my data types

```
Field Name  Data Type
STRATGY_ID  Number
NUMBUDGETS  Number
PDISC_RATE  Number
INC_IMPS    Yes/No
OPT_METHOD  Number
OBJ_FUNC    Number
MININCVAL   Number
EFFFZONE    Number
BUDGETPD    Yes/No
REPORTING   Yes/No
NUM_GROUPS  Number
MATRIX_DEF  Yes/No
NAME        Text
DESC        Text
FLT_CONRTE  Number
WRK_CONRTE  Number
NET_CONRTE  Number
START_YEAR  Number
END_YEAR    Number
CURRENCY    Text
FLEET       Text
NETWORK     Text
NUM_SECSEL  Number
NUM_VEHSEL  Number
ANAL_MODE   Number
NUMPRJOPTS  Number
NUMSECOPTS  Number
INC_NMT     Yes/No
DOECONANAL  Yes/No
DISC_RATE   Number
BASE_OPTN   Text
ACCCOSTS    Yes/No
FATALCOST   Number
INJURYCOST  Number
DAMAGECOST  Number
ALLACCCOST  Number
ENERGY      Yes/No
EMISSIONS   Yes/No
ACCLEFFECT  Yes/No
LOGFILE     Yes/No
INCSENSTVY  Yes/No
NUMSENSCEN  Number
DOASSETVAL  Yes/No
EXCVEHDATA  Yes/No
EXCPERDATA  Yes/No
```

Comment: You need quotes around your strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CURRENCY` is a reserved word in Access SQL, so if you have a column with that name you must enclose it in square brackets. That is, this will fail with "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement." ...

```python
crsr.execute("INSERT INTO Strategy (CURRENCY) VALUES ('USD')")
```

... but this will work:

```python
crsr.execute("INSERT INTO Strategy ([CURRENCY]) VALUES ('USD')")
```

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon said you need quotes around strings and you should not leave empty space between commas. Try to insert 0 or Null or whatever will fit better for that field:

```
VALUES (0, 0, Null, 0,
```

Answer (score 0):

VARCHAR columns require values in quotes. Try building your query like:

```
INSERT INTO Strategy (STRATGY_ID, NUMBUDGETS, PDISC_RATE, INC_IMPS, OPT_METHOD, OBJ_FUNC, MININCVAL, EFFFZONE, BUDGETPD, REPORTING, NUM_GROUPS, MATRIX_DEF, NAME, [DESC], FLT_CONRTE, WRK_CONRTE, NET_CONRTE, START_YEAR, END_YEAR, CURRENCY, FLEET, NETWORK, NUM_SECSEL, NUM_VEHSEL, ANAL_MODE, NUMPRJOPTS, NUMSECOPTS, INC_NMT, DOECONANAL, DISC_RATE, BASE_OPTN, ACCCOSTS, FATALCOST, INJURYCOST, DAMAGECOST, ALLACCCOST, ENERGY, EMISSIONS, ACCLEFFECT, LOGFILE, INCSENSTVY, NUMSENSCEN, DOASSETVAL, EXCVEHDATA, EXCPERDATA) 
VALUES (0, 0, NULL , 0, 1, 0, 0, 95, 0, -1, 0, 0, "Road_Networks_PA", NULL , 1, 1, 1, 2019, 2038, "Reais", "Vehicles 2017", "Road_Networks_PA", 157, 12, 0, NULL, 157, -1, -1, 6.49, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL , 0, -1, -1)
```

Add NULL or "" (empty string) for columns you want to keep null or empty.

Comment: Tried Null, None and empty string. The same error wih all of them

Comment: Show the structure of your table. VARCHAR values should get values in quotes.

Comment: I've edited the question with the structure of the table.